# How to check if a secret is disabled in Google Cloud Secret Manager when using the Google Cloud Java SDK?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-secret-manager

We're using `SecretManagerServiceClient` from the Google Cloud Java SDK, `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-secretmanager:2.1.4`. When using this library, we can create an instance of `SecretManagerServiceClient` which can be used to get a specific secret:

```java
var client = new SecretManagerServiceClient(..);
Secret secret = client.getSecret("my-secret");
```

My question is how I can check if this secret is enabled (i.e. at least one version is enabled) or disabled (all versions are disabled)?